# How do I force Word to recognize a three-letter name if it's also an initialism

Tags: microsoft-word

Unfortunately, by boss goes by "Asi" for short (pronounced Ozzy), which is identical to the initialism ASI.

I have already added Asi to my custom dictionary, but Word always assumes I meant ASI anyway, and underlines it for me to capitalize. I don't want to Ignore Rule, because maybe somewhere else in my document there is an acronym or initialism I missed. Is there a way to force Word to recognize Asi as a word instead of ASI?

Comment: By forcing it you would be ignoring the rule?

Comment: Nah, I don't want to ignore the rule for ALL acryonyms. For example, if I have "Asi" in one spot, and "Cia" in another, I DO want Word to highlight I need to capitalize CIA. If I click the "Ignore Rule" button, Cia won't be highlighted to me. I was curious if I can get Word to associate "Asi" as the word in my dictionary, and not ASI.